# How to enable gzip compression on YAWS?

Tags: gzip, yaws

How do I enable gzip compression on yaws?

I have this information:

```
With this patch, Yaws will add 'Accept-Encoding' in 'Vary' header if the
    support of gzip compression is enabled or if the response is compressed.
    The 'Vary' header can be set using 'yaws:outh_set_vary(Fields)' or by
    returning '{header, {vary, Fields}}' from scripts (where Fields is a list
    of header names).
```

The thing is that I do not know where to add yaws:outh_set_vary(Fields) or how to return {header, {vary, Fields}}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is set `deflate = true` in the server block of your `yaws.conf` config file to enable deflate compression for that server. See [the Yaws config documentation](http://yaws.hyber.org/yman.yaws?page=yaws.conf) for more details about `deflate`, including an explanation of the optional `<deflate> ... </deflate>` block for customizing server compression settings.